# Zestiria vs Berseria map comparison

Tags: tales-of-zestiria, tales-of-berseria

Tales of Berseria and Tales of Zestiria took place in the same world. As shown in the anime, Tales of Zestiria the X, Sorrey and his companions mentioned the story of Artorius Collbrande, the first Shepherd and Velvet Crowe, which is the protagonist of Tales of Berseria, which means that both story happens in the same world.

Now, to the question, this is the world map of Berseria

[image: Berseria World Map]

This is the world map of Zestiria

[image: Zestiria World Map]

**They are nothing alike!** AFAIK, 1000 years are not enough time to cause a massive enough continental drift that would change the shape of the world that much. So to the question, where is Glenwood (the world of Zestiria) in Berseria?

Answer (score 2):

It is the same part of the world.

> Following the awakening of the four Empyreans, the next 1,000 years saw a great change in the landscape of the former Holy Midgand Empire. The islands of Northgand, Westgand, Midgand, Eastgand, and Islegand shifted with the movement of tectonic plates, and by the time of Tales of Zestiria, they formed the continent known as Glenwood.

see [Aselia Wiki](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Glenwood).
There is also a skit in the game regarding the cause of the changes:

> Eizen: With the four Empyreans revived, the land has awakened.
> Eizen: Changes in the earth that once took eons will now happen in a few hundred years.

Source: Skit "No Eruption...So Far" in Tales of Berseria

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the previous answer, it looks like glenwood is only a portion of the entire "Desolation" map.  It looks like eastgand rotated and collided with midgand (us the bay-like area as a reference), and that westgand shifted east to collide with midgand as well, making the super-continent of Glenwood.

So, basically, In Zesteria, we never visit southgand or northgand.  The explorable world is much much smaller.